# how to disable the append value in a angular form

Tags: angular

I have scenario where iam having the forms  with the name field, where i will pass the default value and i need to make this as read only or disabled  and also i can able to append the value with this.
eg: Room-123
Room-is the default value need to read only or disabled
123-can be append with the room and it can be editable.can anyone give a solution for this.

```
public  RoomValue: string='Room';
 public roomDiagForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    id:this.formBuilder.control(''),
    name: this.formBuilder.control(this.RoomValue, Validators.required),
    type: this.formBuilder.control('', Validators.required),
    locationId: this.formBuilder.control(this.location, Validators.required),
  });
```

this is my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one.

Call a function when you find value can change and check your conditions

.ts file

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  contactForm: FormGroup;
  defaultName = "Room";

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.createContactForm();
  }

  createContactForm() {
    this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      fullName: [this.defaultName]
    });
  }

  checkFullname(event) {
    let readOnlyLength = this.defaultName.length;
    let enteredValue = this.contactForm.controls["fullName"].value;
    let keypressed = event.which; // 8 => backspace, 46 => delete
    if (
      (keypressed == 8 && enteredValue.length <= readOnlyLength) ||
      (keypressed == 46 && enteredValue.length <= readOnlyLength)
    ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    if (keypressed != 0 && event.target.selectionStart < readOnlyLength) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

.html

```
<form [formGroup]="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type = "text" name = "fullName" placeholder = "Your full name" formControlName="fullName" (keydown)="checkFullname($event)" (keyup)="checkFullname($event)" (paste)="checkFullname($event)" (cut)="checkFullname($event)">
    <br/>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Send">
</form>
```

working link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yub6rf?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Note: I was also searching to club possible events together as all are calling same function but I am not able to do it.

I found a github link check this as well if you can find a way

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6675

Answer (score 0):

In Angular reactive forms, you can instantiate a new control in the form group with the disable attribute set to true 
Example :

```
this.formBuilder.group({
name : new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true})
})
```

you can also conditionally disable using the below code

```
this.formBuilder.get('name').disable();

this.formBuilder.get('name').enable();
```

you will also have to use the below code

```
 "this.formBuilder.updateValueValidity()"
```

after the disabling or enabling to apply the changes.

Comment: @ Kallam, you didnt catch my question, in the field i have one default value is Room it should be disable or readonly but after the value i will add the value in the same field it should be editable.e.g:Room-123,Room is readonly and 123 is editable.